# Visual c# 2010 express compiling error

Tags: c#

I am new with c# I am using windows 8 and I want to learn this lenguage,
so I open a new proyect and it gives the basics and I only add a single extra line, that should prints a "hi" but when I compile it, it only shows a black window were it suppouse to be my "hi", for compiling I press F6 then when it is compiled I press CTRL+F5 and the black box open, in the tutorials that exact thing works, please help what should I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace intro1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hola"); //this is the only line added by me
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a console application, the "black box" is where the program runs. In the upper left-hand corner of the box is where you should see the word, "hola".

Answer (score 0):

As the program ends immediately after the `Console.WriteLine()`, the "black box" (the console window) should disappear straight away.

To make it pause so you've got time to see what has been printed, add another line to your program:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

this will cause the app to pause until you press a key.